# Printing a shape based on inputs from the user

Tags: java

I am trying to print a shape based on input; the shape is an "x". The inputs must be positive odd ints, and an arbitrary brush character. I have the code completed for the user input, but I need help with the code that actually prints the shape. Here is what I have so far:

```
 public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int height = 5;//Any positive odd int but 5 does not work correctly. Not sure what is going on.
        char brush = '*';

        for (int row = 0; row < height/2; row++) {
            for (int i = row; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print(brush); 
            for (int i = (height/2); i >= 2*row; i--) {
                System.out.print(" "); 
            }

            System.out.print(brush);
            System.out.print("\n");

        }

        for (int row = 1; row < (height/2)+1; row++ ) {
            System.out.print(" "); 
        }
        System.out.print(brush);
        System.out.print("\n"); 
        for (int row = (height/2)-1; row >= 0; row--) {
            for (int i = row; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print(brush); 
            for (int i = (height/2); i >= 2*row; i--) {
                System.out.print(" "); 
            }

            System.out.print(brush);
            System.out.print("\n");

        }

        for (int row = 1; row < (height/2)+1; row++ ) {
            System.out.print(" "); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code cuts off half way through. Come on, you're going to need to do better than this if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: Copied and pasted entire program here. Hope this helps you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a routine to repeat your `char` `n` times. Something like

```
private static String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then, I would prefer to build the `String` with a `StringBuilder` and the `repeat` routine. Like

```
int height = 5;
char brush = '*';
char space = ' ';
int half = height / 2;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int row = 0; row < half; row++) {
    int cols = height - ((row + 1) / 2);
    sb.append(repeat(space, row)).append(brush);
    sb.append(repeat(space, cols)).append(brush);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
sb.append(repeat(space, half)).append(brush);
sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
for (int row = half - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    int cols = height - ((row + 1) / 2);
    sb.append(repeat(space, row)).append(brush);
    sb.append(repeat(space, cols)).append(brush);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Since you haven't learned about buffered io yet, that could also be expressed as

```
int height = 5;
char brush = '*';
char space = ' ';
int half = height / 2;
for (int row = 0; row < half; row++) {
    int cols = height - ((row + 1) * 2);
    System.out.print(repeat(space, row));
    System.out.print(brush);
    System.out.print(repeat(space, cols));
    System.out.println(brush);
}
System.out.print(repeat(space, height / 2));
System.out.println(brush);
for (int row = (height / 2) - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    int cols = height - ((row + 1) * 2);
    System.out.print(repeat(space, row));
    System.out.print(brush);
    System.out.print(repeat(space, cols));
    System.out.println(brush);
}
```

And if you really don't know how to create a method,

```
int height = 5;
char brush = '*';
char space = ' ';
int half = height / 2;
for (int row = 0; row < half; row++) {
    int cols = height - ((row + 1) * 2);
    for (int t = 0; t < row; t++) {
        System.out.print(space);
    }
    System.out.print(brush);
    for (int t = 0; t < cols; t++) {
        System.out.print(space);
    }
    System.out.println(brush);
}
for (int t = 0; t < height / 2; t++) {
    System.out.print(space);
}
System.out.println(brush);
for (int row = (height / 2) - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    int cols = height - ((row + 1) * 2);
    for (int t = 0; t < row; t++) {
        System.out.print(space);
    }
    System.out.print(brush);
    for (int t = 0; t < cols; t++) {
        System.out.print(space);
    }
    System.out.println(brush);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but this is way above my current understanding- is it possible to fix my code, since it is simpler for me? Thanks.

Comment: @ClassicCars I fixed (and greatly simplified) your code. Which part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: I didn't understand any of it- it is not your fault, I am a beginning student, and have not gotten very far in my studies. This seemed like mumbo jumbo if you understand what I mean.I also do not see any of your modifications to the original code. Thanks.

Comment: @ClassicCars I edited my answer. If you read it the examples from the bottom up you'll see how your code evolved into my answer.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. So, in the long run, they perform the exact same operation, they just use different approaches. We have just finished our lecture on methods, so I know how to write methods, we just never discussed buffered io's. This is an introductory course to Java i'm taking. Thank you for your help.